# Select Data With Given Conditiion MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, select

Let's get quick on the problem, which is better described with this table below :

```
ID   Name         Approved
-----------------------------
1    ABC          1
2    ABC          2
3    BCD          1
4    BCD          2
5    BCD          3
6    CDE          1
7    CDE          2
8    CDE          3
9    CDE          4
10   DEF          1
11   DEF          4
12   EFG          4
13   FGH          2
14   FGH          3
```

Now, I want the outputs are ABC, BCD and FGH, because my given condition is selecting every name which approved value is not 4. CDE, DEF, and EFG has a 4 value, so they're not selected. Of course, I still don't know how to construct this condition, so any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I want to take a row with the highest ID number, so the result is ABC with ID 2, BCD with ID 5, and FGH with ID 14. How to solve it?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Can you provide your desired output?

Comment: @BennjoeMordeno, The outputs I desired from above table is CDE, DEF, and EFG which all of them doesn't has a 4 value in table approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct name from myTable where approved != 4;
```

Comment: this will still bring  CDE, DEF, and EFG

Answer (score 1):

```
    select distinct name from mytable x 
where not exists (select 1 from mytable y where x.name = y.name and approved = 4)
```

as for "the update":

```
        select name, MAX(approved) from mytable x 
    where not exists (select 1 from mytable y where x.name = y.name and approved = 4) 
group by name order by  MAX(approved) DESC
```